# Node.js - setTimeout is sometimes not being fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an Node.js application, which does a lot of computing indefinitely. It can be simplified to this:

```js
async function doWork()
{
    await worker.doWork().then(data => {
        // process the data...
    }).catch(e => {
        // log an error
    }).finally(() => setTimeout(() => doWork(), 1000))
}
```

The issue is that this infinite routine randomly stops executing (sometimes the routine works for days, sometimes just a few hours) and I have no idea why. Is there a flaw in my logic or a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I suspect you've oversimplified it. That should run indefinitely. (Although it's odd to use explicit `.then`/`.catch`/`.finally` calls in an `async` function. The point of `async` functions is that you can use standard flow-control structures like `try`/`catch`/`finally`.)

Comment: FWIW re using `try`/`catch`/`finally`, in case it helps: https://pastebin.com/s7AJ06w7

Comment: I guess the execution may be stuck in the `then` block, thus the `finally` block is never executed.

Comment: **Very** good point, that's bound to be it if the above is what you have (in essence). (And it's easy to test to see if that's it.) If the promise never settles (fulfills or rejects), then the next iteration will never happen because the previous one never finished. You *could* use `Promise.race` to time out after a while and start another iteration, but it would be better to find out why it sometimes doesn't complete.

Comment: Implenting a race condition did not resolve the issue. Found online this thread: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149 which at the end mentions similliar issue as I do. My infinite loop is run approximately 50 times at the start of the program, so the event loop is pretty much occupied all the time, if that could help somebody. The promise takes around 1 second to be resolved, processing the data takes around 0-5 ms.